# toLocaleDateString and toLocaleString methods does not respect the machines timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

My computer is with US region settings and date formats and -8h GMT timezone, but i am not exactly in US region. Why when getting the date through new Date i can see that the timezone offset is correct, but when i try and convert it to localedateString i get my really local date string?

```
var date = new Date();
///here date is (for example)  Mon Jan 15 2001 12:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

var localeString = date.toLocateDateString();
///or date.toLocaleString()

/// localeString here comes in my real locale date format 15.01.2001 г or 15.01.2001 г., 12:00:00 when using toLocaleString()
```

Comment: I found the answer. The browser gets the date format from the language that the browser is currently on.

Answer (score -1):

The output of [*toLocaleString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tolocaledatestring) is entirely implementation dependent and is inconsistent across browsers currently in use. It does not necessarily respect system settings (e.g. Chrome does not respect my system settings for the order of the components) and there is no requirement in ECMA-262 for it to do so.

For reliable results, format the output manually in an unambiguous format, e.g. `25 Feb 2017`. A library can help, but if you only need one format then a simple function will suffice.